# Custom Type in PL/pgSQL Function, leaky schema scope? (postgres)

Tags: postgresql

For better or for worse, I have the following custom type and aggregate.

```
create type nanotime as (
  seconds bigint,
  nanos int
);

create function nanotime_max_sfunc(current_max nanotime, candidate nanotime)
returns nanotime
immutable
language plpgsql
as $$
declare
  result nanotime;
begin
  if (current_max.seconds > candidate.seconds) or
     (current_max.seconds = candidate.seconds and current_max.nanos > candidate.nanos) then
    result := current_max;
  else 
    result := candidate;
  end if;
  return result;
end;
$$;

create aggregate max_nanotime(nanotime) (
  sfunc = nanotime_max_sfunc,
  stype = nanotime
);
```

These all reside in the `time` schema.  I'm using flyway to migrate this database.  When I `select max_nanotime(my_nanotime_column)` in a flyway migration -- which is executed in context to the `time` schema -- it works fine.  But when I execute `select time.max_nanotime(my_nanotime_column)` from outside the context of the `time` schema, I get the following:

```
ERROR:  type "nanotime" does not exist
LINE 3:   result nanotime;
                 ^
QUERY:  
declare
  result nanotime;
begin
  if (current_max.seconds > candidate.seconds) or
     (current_max.seconds = candidate.seconds and current_max.nanos > candidate.nanos) then
    result := current_max;
  else 
    result := candidate;
  end if;
  return result;
end;

CONTEXT:  compilation of PL/pgSQL function "nanotime_max_sfunc" near line 3
```

It seems to me that the function `nanotime_max_sfunc` does not retain the scope it was created in.  Which is weird, because the aggregate `max_nanotime` does retain the scope it was created in.  My guess is that aggregates, being defined declaratively, don't require compilation and are fully formed on declaration.  On the other hand, functions, being defined imperatively, are compiled upon use, allowing them to have differing behavior in context to different schemas.

This strikes me as very weird.  Is my assessment accurate?  How do I unambiguously refer to `nanotime` from `nanotime_max_sfunc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you mean with *executed in context to the time schema*, but I'll explain to you how schema resolution works in the context of functions. Then maybe you can figure out what's going on in your case.

When a PL/pgSQL function is first executed in a session, its queries are planned and the plans cached until the end of the session or until something happens that invalidates the plan.

When an SQL statement is planned, all names that are not schema qualified are resolved with the current setting of `search_path`.

To avoid problems like the one you describe, it is best to use the `SET` clause of `CREATE FUNCTION` to fix the value of `search_path` for the function execution (even operators are in schemas in PostgreSQL, so it is hard to schema qualify everything in your function).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Laurenz Albe!  search_path is documented at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createfunction.html under the heading 'Writing SECURITY DEFINER Functions Safely'.  My resulting code, with the change annotated, is:

```
create type nanotime as (
  seconds bigint,
  nanos int
);

create function time.nanotime_max_sfunc(current_max nanotime, candidate nanotime)
returns nanotime
immutable
language plpgsql
set search_path to time   -- <---------------- CHANGE
as $$
declare
  result nanotime;
begin
  if (current_max.seconds > candidate.seconds) or
     (current_max.seconds = candidate.seconds and current_max.nanos > candidate.nanos) then
    result := current_max;
  else 
    result := candidate;
  end if;
  return result;
end;
$$;

create aggregate max_nanotime(nanotime) (
  sfunc = nanotime_max_sfunc,
  stype = nanotime
);
```

It sounds like there are security ramifications to this, so I intend to read that section of the documentation in detail.

Thank you again, Laurenz Albe.